# Statsmodel throwing RuntimeWarning

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I am trying to run below code in Python using Pandas and statsmodel and it keeps throwing me a runtime warning. Does anyone know how to overcome this?. Thank you in advance.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hshh1.png) and
[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDeDi.png)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('appsessions_2016_jan.csv',  delimiter='\x01')`

df_features = df.iloc[:,[3,5,6]]

df_y = df.iloc[:,[4]]

import statsmodels.api as sm

X1 = sm.add_constant(df_features)

est = sm.OLS(df_y, X1).fit()

est.summary()
```

Comment: copy and paste the code and error message into the question as a text so we can reproduce the error. Also share a sample of your data.